# Shell cut delimiter before last

Tags: shell, delimiter, cut

I`m trying to cut a string (Name of a file) where I have to get a variable in the name.
But the problem is, I have to put it in a shell variable, until now it is ok.

Here is the example of what i have to do.

```
NAME_OF_THE_FILE_VARIABLEiWANTtoGET_DATE
NAMEfile_VARIABLEiWANT_DATE
NAME_FILE_VARIABLEiWANT_DATE
```

The position of the variable I want always can change, but it will be always 1 before last. The delimiter is the "_".

Is there a way to count the size of the array to get size-1 or something like that?

OBS: when i cut strings I always use things like that:

```
 VARIABLEiWANT=`echo "$FILENAME" | cut 1 -d "_"`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'_' '{print $(NF-1)}'  file
```

or you have a string

```
awk -F'_' '{print $(NF-1)}'  <<< "$FILENAME"
```

save the output of above oneliner into your variable.

Comment: How do I put it in a variable?
I tried like this:
VARIABLE='awk -F'_' '{print $(NF-1)}'  <<< "$FILENAME"'
It didn`t work.

Comment: @Guilherme the syntax is `var=$(command)`, so you need to say `variable=$(awk ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=_ read -a array <<< "$FILENAME"
variable_i_want=${array[${#array[@]}-2]}
```

It's a bit of a mess visually, but it's more efficient than starting a new process. `${#array[@]}` is the number of elements read from `FILENAME`, so the indices for the array range from 0 to `${#array[@]}-1`.

As of `bash` 4.3, though, you can use a negative index instead of computing it.

```
variable_i_want=${array[-2]}
```

If you need POSIX compatibility (no arrays), then

```
tmp=${FILENAME%_${FILENAME##*_}} # FILENAME with last field removed
variable_i_want=${tmp##*_}       # last field of tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got it... I find someone using a cat function... I got to use it with the echo... and rev. didn't understand the rev thing, but I think it revert the order of the delimiter.

```
CODIGO=`echo "$ARQ_NAME" | rev | cut -d "_" -f 2 | rev `
```

Comment: It reverses the entire string, that way the field you want is always the second one (instead of second last), it then reverses the found field as that is now backwards